# How to fetch data of particular id in mysql using Angularjs

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I have a PHP angularjs based web interface where I should fetch data of a particular user to edit when they are logged in using angular

all I can do is ng-repeat which fetches all the rows of all id's

controller.js file

```
var crudApp = angular.module('crudApp',[]);
crudApp.controller("DbController",['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){

  // Function to get employee details from the database
  getInfo();
  function getInfo(){
    // Sending request to EmpDetails.php files
    $http.post('databaseFiles/Details.php').success(function(data){
      // Stored the returned data into scope
      $scope.details = data;
    });
  }
```

index.php file

```
<tr ng-repeat="detail in details| filter:search_query">
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{detail.trainer_name}}</td>
    <td>{{detail.trainer_team}}</td>
    <td>{{detail.trainer_code}}</td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="editInfo(detail)" title="Edit"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" 
                ng-click="deleteInfo(detail)" title="Delete">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Details.php

```
<?php
// Including database connections
require_once 'database_connections.php';
// mysqli query to fetch all data from database
$query = "SELECT * from pokedstats";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$arr = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$arr[] = $row;
}
}
// Return json array containing data from the databasecon
echo $json_info = json_encode($arr);
?>
```

I want to display only a particular id related row, but I can only be able to fetch all the rows values and display them and edit them. I only want a particular user with a unique id should only be able to edit the row data or delete it.

Comment: This looks like the client-side code, but there's zero context given about the PHP side of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `if` statement within your `editInfo` and `deleteInfo` methods to check the user's permission.  Here is some pseudo code that gives you the idea:

```
$scope.permissionLevelRequired = 3;
$scope.userPermission = 1; // Get this from the database instead

$scope.editInfo(detail) {
  if ($scope.userPermission >= $scope.permissionLevelRequired) {
    // Make changes to `detail`
    ...
  }
}

$scope.deleteInfo(detail) {
  if ($scope.userPermission >= $scope.permissionLevelRequired) {
    // Make changes to `detail`
    ...
  }
}
```

This is client side validation only and it will work for your interface purposes but could be easily hacked.  You may want to validate permissions on the server as well before making changes to the database.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for taking time and answering. Can you please help me with the server related code. I don't want to get into trouble just by writing frontend client-side code. I have added my php code for more details.

Comment: Hi, you're welcome.  That's a lot more complex, far too much to explain in detail but I can point you in the right direction.  You'll need to implement a login system.  Your database needs a `users` table which will have a column `permission`.  When the user logs in, you store the user's permission level in a PHP Session variable.  Every time he tries to edit/delete, you check the session permission.  On the front end, you would still use the code above.  If someone tried to hack, they would be blocked in the backend.

Comment: Thanks again, this approach looks clear and I think I can take over from here. I already have a php login system need to add the permission column and go further. And one more thing how php code can be changed to js code. And how to acquire that idPermission value?

Comment: To do that you just need your login script to return the permission level.  After the user logs in and you've set the session variable, you echo that permission from that same php and store it in your Javascript, just like you would store program data elsewhere.  `idPermission` is just a number you set manually.  And in the database you assign proper permission.  I renamed it to make it clearer.

Comment: In my example, the higher a user's permission number, the greater access they have. Then you can check that their permission number is at least high enough for actions you will number manually.  You could just use true/false instead if that's easier.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try to implement and get back to you if I face any challenges.

Comment: No problem.  Please upvote/accept my answer if it helped you.